# files needed for build don't get copied into xcode project folder with facebook unity sdk

Tags: xcode5, facebook-unity-sdk

we are using the facebook unity sdk (4.3.3) for a project. Building and running works fine but  since we have to handover the xcode project to our client for him to sign the app and push it into the store it is a problem that needed files are not copied into the xcode folder.
They are linked to the external unity project and we have to manually copy and link them everytime we have to deliver a new version. Is there an easy way to copy them into the folder without having to delete the references and linked libs first?

I added a screenshot to clarify: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25768026/xcodeFacebookProblem.jpg

The xcode project folder has a different path than the unity projects path (Unity_CCV2_Share). you can see that the ressources in the group Facebook are located outside the xCode project folder. If I rename the unity folder those files are missing and the build will fail - so there is no way I can let my client do the build himself.
Usually those ressources get copied to the xcode project unless you check "symlink libraries" in the build settings.

Thanks for any help,

Simon

Comment: Hi, you're being a little too vague here.  Can you tell me more about what type of files aren't being copied?  Or are they some specific files?  What do you mean when you say they are linked to the external unity project?

Comment: I added a screenshot to show the files that are not copied to the xcode project. I could try to add them manualy into my xcode project but then I don't know without testing everything throroughly every time I have to make a new build if they are linked correctly. I hope this clarifies some of the issues.

Comment: Hey Simon, this is the first report we've seen of this, is there anything about your setup that might make this happen? If you build a quick test app with the InteractiveConsole scene under examples does this happen as well? Thanks!

Comment: I just did a build with the console and it is exactly the same. The filenames of the items in the facebook group in xcode(screenshot lower left) point to the unity project folder and as soon as I rename or delete it the build will fail. I don't actually want to send the unity folder to my client and tell him where exactly to put it to build the .ipa. Any chance of a fix? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @benp I manually replaced the references with copies that are now in the xcode project. Any word on this issue? This must happen to everyone who want's to handover the xcode project.